# Can't install mysql-server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, server, dpkg, mysql

I cannot install `mysql-server` on my Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. I have already done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as purging all mysql packages multiple times. Running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` yields the following,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2939 kB of archives.
After this operation, 47.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 29273 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback (part of link group my.cnf) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-16 22:16:32 UTC; 48ms ago
  Process: 20084 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 20075 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 16 22:16:32 us-ny-256 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.41) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea how to fix this as I have already gone through multiple StackExchange site threads all which say to purge and remove `MySQL` files, but I continue to get this same error. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Bunsen:

Try with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

- clean: clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
- Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed.
- -f: attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place

Comment: First command result,

E: Unable to locate package mysql.cnf

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql.cnf'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql.cnf'

E: Unable to locate package mysql.conf.d

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql.conf.d'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql.conf.d'

Still same failure as above.

Comment: Hi, Bunsen. Try the rest of commands.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't put line breaks in so it was unclear. I ran them all and still got the same result.